# inconsistency between databases created with pandas and models.py in django

Tags: sql, django, pandas

I am trying to generate a database in sqlite3 with pandas and so far everything is fine, it is generated as I need it, the problem is that when trying to access that database through a models created identical to the one created by pandas it breaks and django does not manages to access that database.

I have the following file "output.txt" which was basically generated by a function in views.py

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
BE9                down        down        
BE9.1              down        down        
BE9.100            down        down        
Lo0                up          up          
Lo8                up          up          
Lo30               up          up          
Lo100              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 100****
Lo111              up          up          Configured by NETCONF
Lo200              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 200****
Gi0/0/0/0          down        down        
Gi0/0/0/1          down        down        
Gi0/0/0/2          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/3          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/4          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/5          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/6          admin-down  admin-down
```

and through that same function there is a fragment that takes that info and transfers it to the database:

```
#Converting txt to Detafrare
df = pd.read_fwf("output.txt")
#debugging df
df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())
df  = df.iloc[:, :4]
#Converting to SQLITE3 database,. If doesn't existe, a nre one will be created
connection = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
#Inserting data into SQLITE database
df.to_sql(
    name = "Devices_App_interfaces",    #this is the name format given by djangoa los nombres de las tablas.
    con = connection, 
    if_exists = "replace",
    index = False)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
#End Process
```

This is how the table looks visually:

[image]

so far everything is perfect, in parallel I create a class in models.py replicating all this format:

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):
    Interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Protocol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

So far everything is fine, I run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate and everything is ok, it doesn't throw any problems, but if I try to call any value of that class from models.py it doesn't do anything, as if it didn't exist and if For example, I add the class to admin.py to see it from the django administrator, it throws me the following error:

OperationalError at /admin/Devices_App/interfaces/

no such column: Devices_App_interfaces.id

obviously Django can't access that data and therefore throws this error, what am I doing wrong? Is there a better or correct way to handle the load of databases externally and access them to display them in an html?

Comment: Can you show how you configured the connection to sqlite database from Django configuration file ? Also, if you can add the content of the migration it generated on `makemigrations`

Comment: is this what you mean? the configuration is the default

    `DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Since the table already exists and you filled it manually, you need to set `managed=False` in your model's Meta options.
Make sure you also add an automatic primary key field.
Read more in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#managed).

Comment: add the Meta class to the model "Interfaces" with managed = False but still the problem persists and same error, I did a makemigration and an additional migration without problem but without success.

Comment: Make sure any field exists in your manually created database. I can't see any id column in your image but expect an id field is part of your migration.

Comment: I think you are right and that is my problem, I added in the code `df.to_sql( index = **True **)` and I am trying to change the name **index** to **id** but I am not succeeding `df.rename(columns={'index': 'id'}, inplace=True) `

Comment: Indeed you were right @Marco, the problem was that the **id** field did not exist and I solved it in the following way `df.to_sql(index = True, index_label="id")` although it could also have been solved by placing `df["id"]=np.arange(len(df))` , thanks!